# math.ceil returns float (1.5)

Tags: python, math, ceil

I need a ceil of a float which it doesn't give to me! Here is the part of the code:

```
    ne = j + e
    nk = ne / 6
    int(math.ceil (nk))
    p2 = nk * 11
    if p2 < p1:
        p1 = p2
    print (p2)
```

j, e and p1 already have values (in this case 4, 5 and 22) and yes, I imported math.

I can't see the problem and I have a few similar lines of code which work. Here it works:

```
    p2 = ne / 6
    int(math.ceil(p2))
    p2 = p2 * 11
    p2 = p2 + (nk * 3.5)
    nk = nj * 11
    p2 = p2 + nj
    nj = j - nn
    p2 = p2 + (nj*2.5)
    print (p2)
```

ne in this case is 6

Comment: `int(math.ceil (nk))` doesn't work in-place, so `nk` is unchanged afterwards. Perhaps you wanted `nk = int(math.ceil (nk))`?

Answer (score 0):

`ceil` doesn't change the value you passed (it cannot - `float` values are immutable); instead, it *returns* the elaborated value - that you are discarding, as you aren't assigning it to anything. You want something like

```
nk = int(math.ceil (nk))
```

> and I have a few similar lines of code which work.

Check better; that cannot possibly work.

Comment: I need to start thinking a bit before i do stuff